# Qt QSerialPort only reads 8 bytes at a time

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am new to Qt and serial programming. 
I am using Qt 5.3 on rhel 7 server.

I receive a packet of size 75 bytes on serial port. On reading the packet using `QSerialPort::readAll()` function, only 8 bytes are read at a time. On checking `QSerialPort::bytesAvailable()` function it shows 8 bytes.

On Google i found that `QSerialPort::readAll()` can read 512 bytes in 1 go.

Am I missing something that needs to specified explicitly?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

That could be a matter of your specific serial port FIFO buffer settings. You could try to change that system settings in your device manager for example. However, I would suggest not to rely on that and connecting to `QSerialPort::readyRead()` signal and read the data and put it in a user defined buffer.

```
QByteArray _MyBuffer;
void MyReadHandler() {
    _MyBuffer.append(readAll());
    if (_MyBuffer.count() >= 75) {
        // Do something with your data...
    } else {
        // Wait for more data...
    }
}
```

In this slot you can wait for a specific amount of data before further processing it.

Answer (score 0):

Partial reads are always possible with serial programming (and communications programming in general). Serial ports are also slow and have no concept of a "packet". The operating system will feed you characters as they arrive. There are ways of optimising this but that doesn't stop your code and protocol from having to deal with comms timing and failures.

You are likely to end up with code with a timer that builds up a packet gradually, checks it and then processes it.